# Cannot export to Excel in IE 11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, export-to-excel, internet-explorer-11

I have a web application that exports data from a gridview to Excel. It works fine in Chrome but doesn't work in IE 11 and Firefox. I see a lot of issues with this when I google it but this error seems to be unique.

```cs
protected void ExportToExcel(List<MapAmericas.Model.Project> Projects)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyFile" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
    this.EnableViewState = false;

    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    gv.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(dataExportExcel_ItemDataBound);

    gv.DataSource = Projects;
    gv.DataBind();

    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(AddExcelStyling()); //this contains the opening html elements
    StringBuilder sbResponseString = new StringBuilder();
    sbResponseString.Append(sw + "</body></html>");
    Response.Write(sbResponseString.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
    Response.End();
}
```

...and the issue I'm getting has to do with not being able to access Temporary Internet Files. I get a popup "Problems during Load" and about a dozen entries: "Missing File...Temporary Internet Files\Content\" and then I get a message reading "Unable to read file".
I had an image to represent the error but I'm not able to upload images.
When I click on one of the links, it loads up my webpage without any styles and I don't get an excel file.
Does anyone know what the issue would be?

Comment: Try replacing Response. with HttpContext.Current.Resoponse. ?

Comment: Also try commenting out Response.Flush() and see if that works too.

Comment: You are not generating actual Excel files, you're generating HTML files masquerading as Excel files. That's got a number of issues associated with it. I describe on [my blog](https://masonmcg.com/blog/entry/properly-generating-excel-files-in-net) how to generate real Excel files.

Comment: Tried the HttpContext,Current and that didn't work...also tried commenting out the Response.Flush and for some reason, I was prompted for a login everytime I tried to Export to Excel. 
I will take a look at mason's approach.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I added 2 lines of code to my existing code and it works. See lines marked with **:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panorama_Project-" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xls");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
        this.EnableViewState = false;

        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        gv.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(dataExportExcel_ItemDataBound);

        gv.DataSource = Projects;
        gv.DataBind();

        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(AddExcelStyling());
        StringBuilder sbResponseString = new StringBuilder();
        sbResponseString.Append(sw + "</body></html>");
        **HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", sbResponseString.Length.ToString());**
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sbResponseString.ToString());
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();**
```

It seems as though it was trying to display the entire Response object which included my page and all linked resources. The Content-Length and replacing Reponse.End and Response.Flush with System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() seems to do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplified version of an Export To Excel function (for a datatable) that I use and one that works for all the browsers. See if this helps. The code is quite similar to yours though:

```
public void ExportDataToExcel(String FileName, DataTable dtData)
{
    // get gridview out of datatable
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.AllowPaging = false;
    gv.DataSource = dtData;
    gv.DataBind();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=" + FileName + ".xls");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        // Apply text style to each Row
        gv.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
    }
    gv.RenderControl(hw);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());

    // commenting this out to resolve this error
    // System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the connection.     
    // The error code is 0x800703E3.
    // HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: @RobVenable do you get any specific error message with your code ?

Comment: It works some of the time but every so often I get a "could not open file" and then a popup "Unable to open file" and sometimes my excel file opens up and is empty and sometimes I get a popup with links to all of the missing Temporary Files and when I click on one of these links, my webpage opens up in the excel file without any styles associated.I'm stumped!